# Help with FTP and then Tar in perl

Tags: perl, ftp, tar

I need to FTP to a server, tar all of the files in a directory, then FTP the tar to a different server.

Once I have the tar placing it on a server is not a problem but I have had trouble trying to figure out how to use Archive::Tar and Net::FTP together.

Comment: Are you trying to back something up?

Comment: Why use perl when you can use Expect? http://www.linux-bsd-central.com/index.php/content/view/26/29/

Comment: @Chris I am actually trying to send archived files to a different server for retrieval.

Comment: Unless the FTP server has a site command for tar, you're not going to be able to do this with FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use ssh or something similar to submit a command on the remote server to create the tar file.  The you'll be able to use Net::FTP to retrieve the resultant file.

Comment: That is what I was planning to do but I have been told by higher powers that currently I cannot use ssh.

Comment: If that is so, you can retrieve the files to a local directory, create the tar file on the local machine and then do the move.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation of Archive::Tar:

```
use Archive::Tar;
my $tar = Archive::Tar->new;
$tar->add_files('file/foo.pl', 'docs/README');
$tar->write('files.tgz', COMPRESS_GZIP);
```